# prove that the following function is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, exponential-function

I am trying to prove that the following function is decreasing.
\begin{align}&f(t)=\frac{1-g(t)}{\sqrt{1+e^t}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{te^t}{2(1-e^t)}\right)&t<0\end{align}where $ g(t)=\dfrac{(1+e^t)(1+t-e^t)}{(1-e^t)^2}$.
I have$$f^{\prime}(t)=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+e^t}}\exp\left(-\frac{te^t}{2(1-e^t)}\right)\left[\frac{(1-g^2(t))e^t}{1+e^t}+\frac{2g(t)e^t}{1+e^t}+\frac{2(1+e^t)}{1-e^t}+\frac{4g(t)e^t}{1-e^t}\right],$$
but I can't show that $f^\prime(t)<0$. Can you help me?

Comment: for the first derivative i have got

Comment: Well, first things first, I'd divide $f'(t)$ by $$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+e^t}}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{te^t}{2-2e^t}\right)$$ to try showing that the remaining part is $\ge 0$. Just to have a little less stuff to carry on.

Comment: I can plot expression into bracket. It is positive. but i can't prove that it is positive.

Comment: Is there any reason why keeping that $g(t)$ implicit should help solving the problem? If not, could you please write down the part between squared brackets as $\dfrac{p(t,\,e^t)}{1-e^{2t}}$, where $p(x,y)$ is a polynomial in two variables?

Comment: the part between squared brackets as $$\frac{e^t}{1+e^t}-\frac{e^t(1+e^t)(1+t-e^t)^2}{(1-e^t)^4}+\frac{2e^t(1+t-e^t)}{(1-e^t)^2}+\frac{2(1+e^t)}{1-e^t}+\frac{4e^t(1+e^t)(1+t-e^t)}{(1-e^t)^3}$$

Comment: Your problem can be simplified a lot. Take $f^\prime (t)$ and replace $t\to \ln z$. Then FullSimplify. Now you "only" have to prove that $$ h(z):=z (z+1) \log (z) (4 z+z \log (z)+\log (z)-4)-2 (z-1)^2 (z (z+4)+1)<0$$ for $0<z<1$. Not sure how to do that yet, but $h(z)$ has some simple features: it goes to $0^-$ for $z\to 1^-$ and to $-2$ for $z\to 0^+$...I will keep you posted if I make some progress.

Comment: I think I can prove the inequality if we can prove that $$\frac{(z-1) \left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{z (z (z+6)+1)}-2 z\right)}{z (z+1)}<\ln z$$ for $0<z<1$, which is numerically verified, but with a very tiny margin...for example, for $z=0.8$ we have the l.h.s. = to -0.223609... and the r.h.s. = -0.223144...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If we run the calcs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Et%2F%281%2Be%5Et%29-e%5Et%281%2Be%5Et%29%281%2Bt-e%5Et%29%5E2%2F%281-e%5Et%29%5E4%2B2e%5Et%281%2Bt-e%5Et%29%2F%281-e%5Et%29%5E2%2B2%281%2Be%5Et%29%2F%281-e%5Et%29%2B4e%5Et%281%2Be%5Et%29%281%2Bt-e%5Et%29%2F%281-e%5Et%29%5E3) on what you wrote, we get 
\begin{align} &-2f'(t)\sqrt{1+e^t}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{te^t}{2-2e^t}\right)=\\
&=\frac{2e^{2t}}{(e^t-1)^4(e^t+1)}\left(2\cosh(2t)-t^2\cosh t-4t\sinh t+4\cosh t-t^2-6\right)\end{align}

After a small argument for the case $t=0$ (it turns out that $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t)$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} f'(t)$ exist) we realise that, to prove that $f$ is strictly decreasing on the whole real line, it is sufficient to prove that $$2\cosh(2t)-t^2\cosh t-4t\sinh t+4\cosh t-t^2-6\ge 0$$
and that the above expression has finitely many zeros.

If we call that function $h(t)$, we have

\begin{align}
\boxed{h(t)}&=2\cosh(2t)-t^2\cosh t-4t\sinh t+4\cosh t-t^2-6\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2k+1}}{(2k)!}t^{2k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!}t^{2k+2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{4}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k+2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4}{(2k)!}t^{2k}-t^2-6\\&\boxed{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n}
\end{align}

With $$\boxed{a_n=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }n\le 2\text{ or }n\text{ is odd}\\
\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n!}-\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}-\dfrac{4}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{4}{n!}&\text{ if }n\ge 4\text{ and }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}}
$$

But $$\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n!}-\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}-\dfrac{4}{(n-1)!}+\dfrac{4}{n!}=\\=\frac{1}{n!}\left(2^{n+1}-n^2-3n+4\right)=\frac{1}{n!}(2^{n+1}-(n+4)(n-1))$$

And you can easily show that $2^{n+1}\ge (n+4)(n-1)$ for all $n\ge 4$. For instance by observing that the inequality holds for $n=4$ and that, for $n\ge 4$, $$\frac{(n+5)n}{(n+4)(n-1)}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\le \frac98\cdot\frac43=\frac32<2$$

> Hence, **all** the $a_n$-s are $\ge 0$.

So, obviously $h(0)=0$ and $h(t)>0$ for all $t>0$.

But $h$ is an even function, hence $h(t)> 0$ for negative values of $t$ as well.

Comment: I enjoyed your answer. Thanks for your attention.